# Was my comment removed?

Tags: support, comments

Either I'm losing my mind, and I didn't post a comment on [this question about Athletics in Cyberpunk](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/380616/how-do-you-level-athletics-in-cyberpunk-2077), or someone deleted it?

IIRC it was just a light-hearted jab at game design - why was it deleted?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Comments are meant to be for short temporary discussion, clarifications, or to add relevant but minor/transient information to the post (such as links to related questions).

The comments on that question were removed by a moderator because they weren't needed to stick around over the long-term. Especially considering that an answer was posted, which pretty much covered the "jump and run around" point you made.

Note that comment removal isn't a 'bad mark' against you or anything, just a regular cleanup process of the site, which regular users can do too by flagging comments. 'It's no longer needed' is a direct reason one can pick:

[image: This comment is outdated, conversational or not relevant to the post]

You can read more on the article on [Comments](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment) in the [Help Center](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help):

> #### What are comments?
>
> Comments are temporary "Post-It" notes left on a question or answer. They can be up-voted (but not down-voted) and flagged, but do not generate reputation. There's no revision history, and when they are deleted they're gone for good.

Comment: Fair enough. I'm not around Arqade consistently enough these days, I know comments like mine used to be left around. I suppose either Arqade or SE as a whole changed the policy on comments, which is fine. Thanks for the kinder answer about it :)

Comment: @Kaizerwolf Some fun comments do still get left around - I get where you're coming from but even stuff like who sees it can be a factor - different moderation styles can result in different outcomes.

Comment: Yeah, i understand. I've taken issue with some moderators rather, militaristic approach recently, but it is what is it. They're mods, I'm not.